# Printing multiple dots not working as expected

Tags: pycharm

I could not figured out why printing multiple dots results in a single one:

```
>>> print('.......')
.
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. You're omitting something here, e.g. replacing `print`, running in some extremely weird shell, or perhaps the string is a variable, not a literal, and the variable contains hidden backspace or carriage return characters?

Comment: What environment are you using? Did you try running this as is?

Comment: It is copied directly from the python console, not variable, just a literal. Python 3.6.3 on Windows.

Comment: See this image taken from Python 3.6.3 on Windows : https://imgur.com/a/A5ulG

Comment: If I execute the print statement from python console I get it right, but from pycharm console which uses python console I get it wrong:

https://imgur.com/a/qW0pZ

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is some pycharm bug, though haven't figured out how to reproduce it stably on my mac. That pycharm console behaviors different with normal one, no matter with or without ipython. Try to enlarge or extend the console window and print again, or print other things before this. And my pycharm doesn't even show the ipython prompt `In[x]:` every time after `print()`.